# Logarithm Problem-Simplification of Long Problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I can't figure out how to solve this problem, so it would be awesome if someone could tell me the technique I need for problems of this sort (as applied to this problem). The answer is 23, but I'm not sure how to get to the answer. I think the first part equals 11, but I'm probably totally off.

$$5^{\log_5 22-\log_5 2} +3 \; \log_2 2^4$$

Comment: The term $5^{\log_5 22 - \log_5 2}$ does equal $11$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$5^{\log_5 22-\log_5 2} +3 \; \log_2 2^4=\frac{5^{\log_5 22}}{5^{\log_5 2}} +12 \; \log_2 2=\frac{22}{2}+12=23$$

we have used that

- $a^{b-c}=\frac{a^b}{a^c}$
- $a^{\log_ab}=b$
- $\log_ab^c=c\log_a b$

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\log_5 22-\log_5 2=\log_5\left(\frac{22}{2}\right)=\log_5 11$$ and $$\log_2 2^4=4\log_2 2=4$$
and $$5^{\log_5 11}=11$$

Answer (score 0):

Some generally useful facts are that for any positive base $b,$
$\log_b x + \log_b y = \log_b(xy)$
and
$\log_b x - \log_b y = \log_b\left(\frac xy\right).$
You can use $\log_b x - \log_b y$ to quickly simplify
$\log_5 22-\log_5 2.$
(Another answer has already used this rule this way.)

For the rest of it,
remember that $x \mapsto \log_b(x)$ and $y \mapsto b^y$
are inverse functions of each other:
$$
 b^{\log_b x} = x \qquad\text{and}\qquad log_b(b^y) = y .
$$

Using these facts you can quickly deal with
$5^{\log_5 11}$ and $\log_2 2^4.$